# Rails 7 paginate without sending API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I want to display `transactions` inside data table. because I expect there will be hundreds of them, I'm using `pagy gem` to paginate the result. Table data comes from client API request. As a response I get an array of hashes from which I extract data.

Here is my code:

Controller where I've made a request:

```
# transactions_controller.rb
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response = client.transactions.list(platform_id: current_user.platform_id, page: 1, per_page: 100)
    @transactions = response.body['data']
  end

  private

  def client
    @client ||= TestAPI::Client.new
  end
end
```

Corresponding view:

#views/transactions/index.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <b>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
      </b>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @transactions.map do |transaction| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= transaction['created_at'] %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= transaction['amount_cents'] %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%== pagy_bootstrap_nav(@pagy) %>
```

The pagination works well how to set it up without reloading the page? now when I use `binding.pry` in the controller to check if the request to the API was made, like below:

```
  def index
    response = client.transactions.list(platform_id: current_user.platform_id, page: 1, per_page: 100)
    binding.pry
  (...)
```

With each transition between pagination pages, a request is sent to the external API. How to send a request just once and operate on a single response?

**[EDIT]**

Controller with Low-Level Caching:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pagy, @transactions = pagy_array(cashed_transactions.body['data'], items: 8)
  end

  private

  def cashed_transactions
    Rails.cache.fetch("merchants/#{current_user.platform_merchant_id}/transactions", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      client.transactions.list(platform_merchant_id: current_user.platform_merchant_id, page: 1, per_page: 100)
    end
  end
end
```

Client API to get list of transactions:

```
  def list(platform_merchant_id:, page: nil, per_page: nil, status: nil, platform_payment_id: nil)
    filters = { 'filters[status]': status, 'filters[platform_payment_id]': platform_payment_id }.compact
    params = { filters:, page:, per_page: }.compact
    get("merchants/#{platform_merchant_id}/transactions", params:)
  end
```

Comment: You are going to need to cache the response. [Official Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: @engineersmnky but I cannot use just memonization here for the response, am I right?

Comment: Correct. Each request is separate so memoization will not help in this case

Comment: Damn, is there any other way to use Redis? I have to avoid adding the operational overhead of Redis

Comment: @engineersmnky could you please take a look at to my edited question? still sends a request and I don't know why